# Computer can be powered on once after new SSD install

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, windows-8.1, power-supply

My computer has a strange behavior since I installed a new SSD (Samsung Evo 840).

When I pushed start button the first time after connecting the new internal SSD everything was ok. I managed to install my O.S (I tried win8.1) on this brand new SSD and the computer was still on for about 5hours. After that I clicked on shutdown and I went off.

Now I can't power it on normally again: If I push power button there is no sign of life. Even fan aren't moving, just like if there was no power at all. 
**The only way to start my computer is to remove power cable, wait around 30s, then put it back and press start button**. The computer launchs and boot this way with no sign of other failure whatsover (no random shutdown).

## What I've tried:

- Remove internal Wifi card I don't use in order to check if since I've introduced a new drive there's a need to much power. It's a Corsair 650W power I've bought 3 months ago. Nothing changed.
- Put my SSD on another power supply
- Vacuum cleaning
- Check power cables are rightfully plugged in.

## What I've not tried:

- Install SSD firmware/drivers (Samsung Evo 840), I've not installed them.
- Flash my motherboard by removing/putting back motherboard CMOS battery.
- Change motherboard CMOS, I've read on another forum this could be CMOS related but that would be strange It fails as soon as I install a new drive.
- Try with another Power Supply, since it's a brand new power supply and I've never had power issue before I installed this SSD I don't think it's related to this power supply but maybe?
- Try with another motherboard (because It would be a lot of pain).

What should I try first?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Hello, my initial thoughts would be a psu problem, if the PC is not even getting power this would suggest a problem with the psu. I don't think there is an issue with the ssd as it will boot when forced. Maybe odd coincidence or something happened whilst changing out the drives but unfortunately though its a new psu, I would highly reccomend changing out the psu just to see if it will boot, if not then the next steps would be the motherboard and so on, the hdd or ssd should have very little to do with the power of a system. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, found out It was related to **Windows 8.1 "Turn on fast startup"** feature inside **"Change what the power buttons do"** panel. It is enabled by default. Since I've turned it off I can power on and off without problem. I'll wait several days to check if this is only a temporary solution or if It was the issue. Thanks guys for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to remove **Windows 8.1 "Turn on fast startup"** feature inside **"Change what the power buttons do"** panel.

I think it could have been PSU related as Rasmus and Ashley answered but this time it was not.
After several days everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem with a new computer i helped assemble for a friend. We contacted the site we bought it from and said we suspected a shortcircuit of some sorts in the power supply. They sent over a new one and it works fine now. So my guess would be to try with another power supply or just contact the store/site you bought it from.

Answer (score 0):

the ssd is overvolted. I tried power supply with 12v power and not longer lasting. after I connect again, the ssd is fried and exploded then ssd is destroyed and dead. I bought new ssd. [TESTED] When I cut the yellow wire (12v supply), the ssd is longer lasting and enjoy to use ssd forever!!!